# Mod Security2 deactivation rule only from a specified IP addresses

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ip, mod-security, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to disable a rule by Mod Security2, only for one specified IP addresses?

Only for one specified IP addresses **&** only for one specified path ( */administrator* ) ?

I tried this:

```
<LocationMatch /administrator>
Allow from 123.456.78.999
 SecRuleRemoveById 000000
</LocationMatch>
```

But it does not work. :(

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server and just I managed to install mod security2.

Answer (score 0):

Did not try it, but I think it should work

```
<LocationMatch /administrator>
  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRule REMOTE_HOST "@ipmatch 1.2.3.4" \
    "id:12345,phase:2,t:none,pass,nolog,noauditlog,ctl:ruleRemovebyID=000000"
  </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```